# Set timeout on ffmpeg process

Tags: ffmpeg

Sometims ffmpeg never completes, and thereby preventing conversions of other videos in the queue. Is it possible to set some sort of timeout in ffmpeg such that it terminates if it isnt finished within some given time, example 5 min

My command looks like this today:

```
 ffmpeg -i /home/tomcat/bsafevideo/1efef9daa7f5000ed83d67f6fbd0e7d9/aad5adc307c4dd7e457509423a7f3734/69451c31cd592e86138423f6849d8141 -y -r 24 -ar 22050 -f mov -vf [in]transpose=1[rt0],[rt0]scale=iw*480/ih:480[sc0],[sc0]pad=640:480:140[pd0],movie=/srv/bsafe/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/resources/images/logo_watermark.png [wm],[pd0][wm] overlay=W-w-140:0[out] /home/tomcat/bsafevideo/1efef9daa7f5000ed83d67f6fbd0e7d9/aad5adc307c4dd7e457509423a7f3734/69451c31cd592e86138423f6849d8141.mov -ar 22050 -b 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -f ogg -vf [in]transpose=1[rt0],[rt0]scale=iw*480/ih:480[sc0],[sc0]pad=640:480:140[pd0],movie=/srv/bsafe/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/resources/images/logo_watermark.png [wm],[pd0][wm] overlay=W-w-140:0[out] /home/tomcat/bsafevideo/1efef9daa7f5000ed83d67f6fbd0e7d9/aad5adc307c4dd7e457509423a7f3734/69451c31cd592e86138423f6849d8141.ogg -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 -profile baseline -vf [in]transpose=1[rt0],[rt0]scale=iw*480/ih:480[sc0],[sc0]pad=640:480:140[pd0],movie=/srv/bsafe/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/resources/images/logo_watermark.png [wm],[pd0][wm] overlay=W-w-140:0[out] /home/tomcat/bsafevideo/1efef9daa7f5000ed83d67f6fbd0e7d9/aad5adc307c4dd7e457509423a7f3734/69451c31cd592e86138423f6849d8141_mp4.mp4
```

UPDATE. Thanks LordNeckBerd, you pointed me in right direction!

So I see now its kind of not ffmpeg really hanging, the issue is that my java code which reads the inputstream from the linux process will block since ffmpeg never returns a end of line, which I see now when Im running the command. This is the blocking line, it waits for more input from me.

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

So its two issues here now. First is why this particular conversion is failing, and second, how to make sure ffmpeg is not making this (for my Java process) blocking command asking for more input.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2>ffmpeg -i C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-   base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232 -y -r 24 -ar 22050 -f mov C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232.mov -ar 22050 -b:v 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -f ogg C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232.ogg -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232_mp4.mp4
ffmpeg version N-54762-g38b701a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jul 15 2013 18:47:20 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --  enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-  libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable- libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable- libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable- libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame - -enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable- libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 81.101 /  3. 81.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-  base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
Duration: 00:00:10.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 394 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 264 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 4:3, 10.95 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 127 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
 [ogg @ 00000000027d7860] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[mp4 @ 00000000027dacc0] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 0000000003e6b9c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000003e6b9c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000003e6b9c0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0000000003e6b9c0] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec -   Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3  deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1  me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1  chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1  interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0  direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40  intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69  qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 00000000027db4a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000027db4a0] MB rate (108000000) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 00000000027db4a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00000000027db4a0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 00000000027db4a0] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec -  Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3  deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1  me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1  chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1  interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250  keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0  qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to 'C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-  base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1  DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #1, ogg, to 'C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232.ogg':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
Stream #1:0(eng): Video: theora (libtheora), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 1500 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #2, mp4, to 'C:/projectsGit/bsafe-server/classes/test/bs-base/video/ac7601e2bc3bc1545cd30ad3160f5232_mp4.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-15 05:46:02
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (h264 -> libtheora)
Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (h264 -> libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #2:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Comment: The first step is to see why ffmpeg never completes. Please show the complete ffmpeg console output from your command.

Comment: Hi LordNeckbeard! Thanks for your help, you pointed me in right direction, I updated my question according to your comment.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles on this question when [FFmpeg Android Java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) hangs waiting for user input, setting the timeout, `setTimeout(long timeout)` would kill the process, and might be appropriate in some cases.